# Why do I need Babel when using Typescript targeting ES2015? (aurelia-skeleton-navigation-typescript-webpack)

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, aurelia

I'm currently trying to understand the project settings of the **aurelia skeletons** by making my own skeleton from scratch.

What i do not understand in the typescript-webpack skeleton is, why do i need to install babel when i use typescript and targeting es2015 in tsconfig.json? Is it used as a compiler? Or as a transpiler or polyfill at runtime?

I thought it should work like that: install the ts-loader for webpack, webpack uses typescript to compile .ts files to es2015 .js files, done.

Or do I miss something in the build (and/or runtime) part?

Comment: You target es2015, which is not supported in some browsers. That's why you have to use babel.

Comment: thx! i obviously didnt pay enough attention to the different aurelia skeletons project settings, i was working first a long time on the typescript only project which worked even in IE9 (with  one or two polyfills, but no babel), the project was targeting es5, then i went to the webpack skeleton and saw the babel dependency...and es2015 target... i completely forgot that es5 is not es2015, stupid. so the better question would be now if there is a reason why the webpack projects targets es2015...

Comment: I'd suggest using the aurelia-cli to start a project and starting from there. https://github.com/aurelia/cli. I think the cli has more up to date examples